# Looping command for multiple files similar to Stata in R

Tags: r, for-loop, stata

I am working multiple files (each file corresponds to each year from 2008 to 2020) using Stata and R. For question purpose, 3 example Stata data files are named as: "file_2008.dta", "file_2009.dta" and "file_2010.dta". I would like to rename and label the variables corresponding to each year. Then, I would like to merge these files using looping. I tried in Stata with the codes below. I would like to learn how I can reproduce similar output using looping in R.

Data examples in Stata
file_2008.dta

```
 clear
input byte(id x1 x2 y1 y2)
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
end
save "C:/Users/sai/Desktop/file_2008.dta"
clear
input byte(id x1 x2 y1 y2)
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
end
save "C:/Users/sai/Desktop/file_2009.dta"
clear
input byte(id x1 x2 y1 y2)
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
end
save "C:/Users/sai/Desktop/file_2010.dta"
```

Desired output

```
clear
input byte(id y1_08 y2_08 x1_08 x2_08 y1_09 y2_09 x1_09 x2_09 y1_10 y2_10 x1_10 x2_10)
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
end
save "C:/Users/sai/Desktop/file_2008_2010.dta"
```

In Stata, I have used the following codes to get desired output.

```
global workdir "C:/Users/sai/Desktop/"
*for rename and label variables corresponding to each year
foreach name in "08" "09" "10" {
    use "${workdir}file_20`name'.dta",clear
    rename x1 x1_`name'
    label variable x1_`name' "year 20`name'"
    rename x2 x2_`name'
    label variable x2_`name' "year 20`name'"
    rename y1 y1_`name'
    label variable y1_`name' "year 20`name'"
    rename y2 y2_`name'
    label variable y2_`name' "year 20`name'"
    order y*, before (x1*)
    save "${workdir}file_20`name'.dta",replace
}
*merging multiple files 
use  "${workdir}file_2008.dta", clear
forvalues i=2009/2010 { 
    sort id
    merge 1:1 id using "${workdir}file_`i'.dta", nogen
}
save "${workdir}file_2008_2010.dta", replace
```

For R, example data and desired output are as follow.

```
file_2008 <- tribble(
  ~id,~x1,~x2,~y1,~y2,
  1,  1, 1, 1, 1,
  2,  2, 2, 2, 2,
  3,  3, 3, 3, 3
)

file_2009 <- tribble(
  ~id,~x1,~x2,~y1,~y2,
  1,  1, 1, 1, 1,
  2,  2, 2, 2, 2,
  3,  3, 3, 3, 3
)
file_2010 <- tribble(
  ~id,~x1,~x2,~y1,~y2,
  1,  1, 1, 1, 1,
  2,  2, 2, 2, 2,
  3,  3, 3, 3, 3
)

# desired output 
file_2008_2010 <- tribble(
  ~id,~y1_08,~y2_08,~x1_08,~x2_08, ~y1_09,~y2_09,~x1_09,~x2_09,~y1_10,~y2_10,~x1_10,~x2_10,
  1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,
  2,  2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2,
  3,  3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3
)
```

Comment: What have you tried in R and where do you get stuck? Is there a way to make your question reproducible? This might help people who are not versed in Stata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your dta files are in a folder of path `"./data_folder"` (i.e. in a subfolder of R's working directory), with `tidyverse` for wrangling and `haven` for dta import,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)

# Function to load the dta's, and append the year from the file name as a variable
fx_load_lable_dta <- function(path) {
  
  str_yearlabel <- sub("^.*(?=\\d\\d[.]dta$)", "", path , perl = TRUE) %>% sub("[.]dta$", "", . )
  df <- haven::read_dta(path)
  df$year_label <-  str_yearlabel
  df
}

list.files(path = "./dta_folder/", full.names = TRUE) %>% #Create a list of file's paths
  map_df(.f = fx_load_lable_dta) %>% #Iterate the list of file paths through the function and append all data frames
  pivot_longer(cols = x1:y2) %>% #Wrangle to get your desire outpu
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, 
              names_from = c(name, year_label), 
              values_from = c(value))
# A tibble: 3 x 13
     id x1_08 x2_08 y1_08 y2_08 x1_09 x2_09 y1_09 y2_09 x1_10 x2_10 y1_10 y2_10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```